# Android animation picture change with swipe in and out (up,left,right,down)

Tags: android, image, animation, imageview, android-animation

Is there an easy possibility to change an image in an imageview and let the imagechange animate by swiping out for example to the right and let the new image swipe in from left or swipe out downside and swipe in from upside?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by using [translate-animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html). First, prepare a translate animation object that specifies say sliding out to the right by 200 pixels. Set the animation on the imageview and start the animation. Once the animation ends (set animation listener on it), change the imageview to your new image and again use a translate animation to slide it in from the left, in the same way.